# Post on timeline with getsteam.io and getting permission denied

Tags: reactjs, permissions, getstream-io

I build a site using getstream.io
everything works, I can comment, like, see the post on the timeline etc...
The only trouble, I can't post on the timeline.

I used StatusUpdateForm component, and I got a :
'You dont have permission to do this'

is it about my token ?

token and id look like this:

```
feedGroup: 'user', 
userId: 'EVTb88d8edf-da22-3d32-b234-3cc234d23d64', // user token
token: "eyJOeXaioiJFV1QiLCjJdjiCoIJIUzI1niJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiVkJIJ2KJdiZjzekjzudZHi2OiezjelzzkdiJZEIJ2IdzijdziZIpkoki?.uJ2dhdVP_Ny2j-T5jzeIZAEmozekaPDOZJF823jDjs" // stream token
```

Here my StatusUpdateForm:

```
<StatusUpdateForm
   feedGroup={this.props.feedGroup}
   userId={this.props.userId} />
```

I expected to be able to post on my timeline since I can like, and comment...

Comment: Could you provide example code of your `StatusUpdateForm` usage that leads to the error?

Comment: @Nekuromento thanks for your answer, I updated my initial post !

Comment: the token you are using is not valid, how did you generate it?

Comment: Actually it was, I had an answer from getstream.io and it's a limitation because I tried to post on an other timeline than my current user. 
https://github.com/GetStream/react-activity-feed/issues/23